# Create Fishnet on Landsat footprint?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, landsat, vector-grid

I have a Landsat footprint polygon shapefile that I simply want to create a 6 x 6 fishnet on. I thought this would be simple, but every time I run the tool I get a fishnet output that extends longer than the original footprint and is shorter in height. I think the problem may stem from the fact that the footprint is slanted and the y-axis may be a different angle than the x-axis.

I used Feature Vertices to Points and then Add XY Coordinates to get the exact coordinates of the footprint polygon's corners. Then within the Fishnet tool, I used the footprint's extent as the 'Template Extent', the bottom left corner as the 'Origin Coordinate', the top left corner as the 'Y-Axis Coordinate', and the top right corner as the 'Opposite corner of Fishnet.'

Coordinate system is WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_18S.

Any ideas for how I can fix this and generate a properly placed fishnet?

Here's the strange looking fishnet output:

[image: Fishnet]

And here are the parameters I passed into the fishnet tool, along with the proper corner coordinates in the top left of the image (Point_X and Point_Y):

[image: Fishnet tool screenshot]

Comment: An easier way to get the extents of the polygon would be to open properties -> source. Have you tried flipping the coordinates around to see if maybe x was inputted into y and vice versa?

Comment: Maybe theres a coordinate system error. Try checking whether the fishnet feature class has the same CRS as your landsat data and the same as the whole data frame.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The Coordinate Systems all match up. I'll try switching some of the XY coordinates and see if that's the fix.

Comment: Can you use Copy Python Snippet in your Geoprocessing | Results window to show us what parameters you passed to CreateFishnet?  Are you expecting square cells in your fishnet and/or what size should they be?

Comment: Does the fishnet layer have a defined coordinate system? And if not, could the data frame not be in the same one?

Comment: The output coordinate system is the same as the one that was input with the landsat polygon (and I checked the data frame's before running the tool as well). I am expecting rectangular cells (just a 6x6 grid within the landsat footprint). Here is the python snippet: arcpy.CreateFishnet_management("C:/Landsat/Shapefiles/Scratch1/fishnet3.shp","223122.902847 4244274.58422","266744.967575 4410255.40647","0","0","6","6","447614.673105 4372719.14612","LABELS","wrs_dec_va_proj15033","POLYLINE")

Answer (score 0):

As a comment you provided a line of ArcPy code that I just tested using:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.CreateFishnet_management("C:/Temp/test.shp","223122.902847 4244274.58422","266744.967575 4410255.40647","0","0","6","6","447614.673105 4372719.14612","LABELS","wrs_dec_va_proj15033","POLYLINE")
```

This reported an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    arcpy.CreateFishnet_management("C:/Temp/test.shp","223122.902847 4244274.58422","266744.967575 4410255.40647","0","0","6","6","447614.673105 4372719.14612","LABELS","wrs_dec_va_proj15033","POLYLINE")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 15397, in CreateFishnet
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Create Fishnet). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter template.
```

I am reluctant to investigate this error because the code snippet does not seem to match the parameters that you have used in the picture of your tool dialog.